# wordpress get_search_query() in functions.php is empty

Tags: php, wordpress

When doing wp_query with get_search_query() in functions.php i cant get the search term.

```
function load_posts() {
    $ppp = (isset($_POST["ppp"])) ? $_POST["ppp"] : 20;
    $page = (isset($_POST['page'])) ? $_POST['page'] : 1;
 
    $args = array(
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
        'post_status' => array('publish'),
        'orderby'           => 'post_date',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'paged'             => $page,
        's' => get_search_query(), //i need access to search term here
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    echo '<pre>' . var_export($args, true) . '</pre>';
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts','load_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts','load_posts');
```

This returns in functions.php:
As you can see under `'s' => '',` search is empty.

```
array (
  'suppress_filters' => true,
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
  'post_status' => 
  array (
    0 => 'publish',
  ),
  'orderby' => 'post_date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'posts_per_page' => '20',
  'paged' => '1',
  's' => '',
)
```

Running the exact same code in search.php it has the search value. (only difference is posts_per_page but that does not matter)

```
array (
  'suppress_filters' => true,
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 
  array (
    0 => 'publish',
  ),
  'orderby' => 'post_date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'paged' => 1,
  's' => 'Hydro',
)
```

To execute the code in functions.php i do an ajax request to call load_posts function
(this works fine)

```
jQuery.post(ajaxUrl, {
            action: "load_posts",
            page: page,
            ppp: ppp
        })
```

Im happy to provide any more information if needed, but I do not understand why the search value is not available in functions.php

Any help appreciated!

Edit: I found this thread which says it is to early to call is_search() function in functions.php because it loads before search. Which I guess is the same problem for get_search_query(). But still need access to the search term in function.php and not sure how to get that value.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53608188/11524115

Comment: Does this answer your question ? - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142410/how-to-get-search-term-and-use-in-function

Comment: Which hook are you using in function.php

Comment: add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts','load_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts','load_posts');

Answer (score 0):

The [`parse_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_query/) action should be used since WordPress will have setup most things for you at this point.

> parse_query is an action triggered after WP_Query->parse_query() has set up query variables (such as the various `is_` variables used for conditional tags).

You'll probably also want to double-check that you are on the main query, too, which this code does.

```php
add_action(
    'parse_query',
    function() {
        if(is_main_query() && is_search()){
            var_dump(get_search_query());
        }
    }
);
```

**Edit**

With your updated post that shows how you are using this, the above won't work.

The function `get_search_query` is ultimately a call to [`get_query_var`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) which is just a global function that accesses the global `$wp_query` object. You, however, **aren't using the global `$wp_query` object**, and instead you are creating your own by invoking `new WP_Query()`. I think the simplest thing for you to do is to just grab the query parameter using `$_GET['s']`. (I'm assuming `s`, but obviously change that if you are using something else.)

Comment: That code works in function.php but still not sure how to get that value to my load_posts() function in functions.php

Comment: I updated question with the load_posts() function to make it more clear